# How to get Harbinger price feed from Taquito

Tags: taquito

I get an http error 'Key not found' The contract is a harbinger (coinbase carthage) storage contract.  What is the correct 'get' param ?

Tezos.contract.at('KT1P7D7jt3PfjMpsEKPyao1kHQR93t7XR5zh')
.then( myContract => {
return myContract.storage()
.then ( myStorage => {
//When called on a bigMap, the get method returns a promise
return myStorage['oracleData'].get({
0 : 'XTZ-USD'
})
}).then (valueBigMap => {
println(`The value associated with the specified key of the bigMap is ${valueBigMap}.`);
})
})
.catch(error => println(`Error: ${JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}`));

Answer (score 2):

From my experience with Harbinger I believe it's best practice to pull the data from the Normalizer contracts, as opposed to the Storage contracts. The Normalizer contract gives you a volume weighted average so you know the numbers won't be skewed.

Here's how I pulled the price feed with async/await syntax:

```
    // Ping Oracle contract
    const contract = await Tezos.contract.at(exchange ?? "KT1P7D7jt3PfjMpsEKPyao1kHQR93t7XR5zh");
    // Grab contract storage
    const contractStorage: { [key: string]: any } = await contract.storage();
    // Get asset codes (ex: XTZ-USD, BTC-USD etc)
    const { assetCodes } = contractStorage;

    // Grab the computed prices from the BigMap
    const assetsWithPrices = await Promise.all(
      assetCodes.map(async (assetCode: string) => {
        const { computedPrice } = await contractStorage["assetMap"].get(assetCode);
        // Computed price comes without decimal so add decimal
        const bigNumberPrice = computedPrice.c[0];
        const bigNumberPriceString = bigNumberPrice.toString().split("");
        bigNumberPriceString.splice(bigNumberPriceString.length - 6, 0, ".");
        const price = Number(bigNumberPriceString.join("").toString());
        return { [assetCode]: price };
      })
    );
```

If you'd like to see it in action you can visit https://oracles.vercel.app

The github repo for this, which includes the above code, can be found at https://github.com/sean-magin/oracles if you'd like to inspect the code closer.